# Error with date functions in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, posixct, posixlt

I want to extract the date from a timestamp stored in R as a POSIXct class.

e.g.

```
> str(wdt$v_timestamp)
POSIXct[1:15399], format: "2011-08-15 00:00:00" "2011-08-18 18:30:00" "2011-07-20 22:15:00" "2011-07-05 03:30:00" "2011-09-09 00:30:00" ...
```

When I do the conversion, it seems to stumble

```
> wdt[,v_date:=trunc(v_timestamp, "day")]
Error in `[.data.table`(wdt, , `:=`(v_date, trunc(v_timestamp, "day"))) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(wdt, , `:=`(v_date, trunc(v_timestamp, "day"))) :
  Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 15399 items of column 'v_date' (recycled leaving remainder of 10 items).
```

I think because `trunc` is return a list which it then attempts to recycle.

This works however.

```
> str(wdt$v_date) > wdt[,v_date:=as.POSIXct(trunc(v_timestamp, "day"))]
> str(wdt$v_date)
 POSIXct[1:15399], format: "2011-08-15" "2011-08-18" "2011-07-20" "2011-07-05" "2011-09-09" "2011-04-20" "2010-12-03" "2011-01-31" ...
```

I see the error message about the list but I don't really understand. And is there a better way to have done this?

Comment: `trunc` converts it to `POSIXlt` class which isn't working so well with `data.table`. Just do `wdt[,v_date:=as.IDate(v_timestamp)]` instead. Or use `substr` if you don't care about the `Date` class.

Comment: Thanks. Not seen the IDateTime class before.

Comment: It's pretty much the same as `as.Date` just an integer representation instead of numeric.